# how to solve "Object of class Closure could not be converted to int"

Tags: php, yii2

I was going to call the data from model in gridview. I installed advanced grid view via composer and I am using \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn. but the prolem ProgressColumn widget is not taking

```
 'value'=>function($model){
          return $model->paxtashart;
         },
```

as int value, it gives me error: **Object of class Closure could not be converted to int**

is there any possiblity that I can convert it to int or any other alternative?

here let me present you my entire code:

```
  [


        'class' => \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::className(),
        'attribute' => 'paxta_given',
        'size' => \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::SIZE_LARGE,
        'isAnimated' => true,
         'value'=>function($model){
           $model->paxtashart;
         },

        // 'maxValue'=> $fermercha->paxtashart,
        // 'minValue'=> $fermercha->paxta_given,
        'progressBarClass' => function ($model, $column) {
            return $model->{$column->attribute} > 60
                ? \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::STYLE_SUCCESS
                : \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::STYLE_WARNING;
        },
    ],
```

*I tried this way:
    $model->paxtashart
but it is jsut giving me 1 value for all attributes, it is not helping
here is what my model looks like:*

```
 <?php

    namespace app\models;

    use Yii;

    /**
     * This is the model class for table "fermer".
     *
     * @property integer $id
     * @property string $FIO
     * @property integer $tuman_id
     * @property string $Massiv
     * @property integer $ferhojalik
     * @property integer $maydoni
     * @property integer $paxtamay
     * @property integer $paxtashart
     * @property integer $gallamay
     * @property integer $gallashart
     * @property integer $bog
     * @property integer $uzum
     * @property integer $poliz
     * @property integer $sabzavot
     * @property integer $chorva
     */
    class Fermer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'fermer';
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [

                [['tuman_id', 'ferhojalik', 'maydoni', 'paxtamay', 'paxtashart', 'gallamay', 'gallashart', 'paxta_given', 'poliz', 'sabzavot', 'chorva','paxta_done'], 'integer'],
                [['FIO', 'Massiv'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
                [['image'], 'file',  'extensions' => ['png','jpg','jpeg']],

            ];
        }

        public function upload()
        {
            if ($this->validate() and $this->image->baseName) {
                $this->image->saveAs(Yii::$app->basePath.'/web/uploads/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'id' => 'ID',
                'FIO' => 'ФИО',
                'tuman_id' => 'Туман номи',
                'Massiv' => 'Массив номи',
                'ferhojalik' => 'Фермер хўжалиги номи',
                'maydoni' => 'Майдони',
                'paxtamay' => 'Пахта майдони',
                'paxtashart' => 'Пахта майдони шартнома режаси (тонна)',
                'gallamay' => 'Ғалла майдони',
                'gallashart' => 'Ғалла майдони шартнома режаси (тонна)',
                'paxta_given' => 'Пахта шартнома бўйича топширилган тонна',
                'image' => 'Расм',
                'poliz' => 'Полизчилик',
                'sabzavot' => 'Сабзавотчилик',
                'chorva' => 'Чорвачилик',
            ];
        }
            // return $this->hasone(Extraagri::className(), ['id' => 'po_item_no']);

     public function getDone()
     {
        return  $this->hasone(done::classname(),['id'=>'paxta_done']);
     }

    /*      public function getPoitem()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Poitem::className(), ['id' => 'po_item_no']);
        }*/

     /* public function getExtraagri()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Extraagri::className(), ['id' => 'id']);
        }
    */


    }
```

Comment: What if you add return before that like `return $model->paxtashart`?

Comment: I added return but still is giving me that error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to int

Comment: Try assigning the closure to a variable in advance. Like `$paxtashart = function($model){
      return $model->paxtashart;
     }`. Then invoke it like `value=> (int) $paxtashart()`. BTW, what is `$model`? Can you add more code here!

Comment: here is my model bro

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous function is an instance of Class closure. Try following variation

```
    //assign the closure to variable
    $value = function($model){
           return $model->paxtashart;
         }  
    $progressBarClass = function ($model, $column) {
            return $model->{$column->attribute} > 60
                ? \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::STYLE_SUCCESS
                : \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::STYLE_WARNING;
        }   
    [
        'class' => \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::className(),
        'attribute' => 'paxta_given',
        'size' => \yiister\grid\widgets\ProgressColumn::SIZE_LARGE,
        'isAnimated' => true,
        'value'=>(int)$value($model), //invoke the closure and cast as integer
        'progressBarClass' =>(string)$progressBarClass($model, $column), //invoke the closure and cast as string
    ],
```

Comment: thank bro, it just showed me this error: Undefined variable: model

Comment: this line bro -->   'value'=>(int)$value($model)

Comment: I assume you have initialized the $model somewhere before this part! Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Object of class Closure could not be converted to int
1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\tomorqa_local\vendor\yiister\yii2-advanced-grid\src\widgets\ProgressColumn.php

Comment: What did you defined as $model? What is the value of `$model->paxtashart`?

Comment: bro $model->paxtashart is integer values, that are 300, 500 and 1000, i dont know here is the error is coming from

Comment: error is showing this line: $percents = ($model->{$this->attribute}) * 100 /  $this->value;

Comment: If you can get the value for `$model->paxtashart` then no need for closure. Try to solve that problem first.

Comment: yes I can get the value but if I make $model->paxtashart  there, i am getting the same value for all attributes

Comment: Still the problem is not the closure. The problem is the `$model` initialization and usage. You pasted entire `$model` class which is not useful. Instead you should present the `$model` initialization and how it reaches to this part of the code.